# Shrinkwrap to project in the direction of view

Tags: python

I require some help with the shrinkwrap modifier to project in the direction of "VIEW". Currently I have a few choices. positive, negative, X,Y,Z.

Is there a script for this.. kindly appreciate any help. In the photo you can see that it projects in the z direction.

This I use to block out undercuts.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. If you're able to add a bit more context to your question as to *why* you need a view specific projection that may help people find a solution.

Comment: A dentist will cut back a tooth for a crown. Sometimes it's not possible to trim it down without undercuts and these need to be blocked out for a crown to fit. The photo shows a dental model with a shrink-wrap plane over the top. Ideally I do not want to move the model, so I have moved the camera view angle to make sure the tooth preparation is seen in its entirety.  A shrink-wrap from this angle will cut out many steps of moving the model for each tooth to be blocked out

Answer (score 1):

The Project directions are in *local* coordinates rather than global (world) axes. Therefore, to change the direction of the projection you can simply rotate the object such that it faces in the direction you want the projection to be in.

In order for it to always point towards the camera you can simply add a Constraint to Track To the camera.